# Is Simple Injector dropping support for CommonServiceLocator?

Tags: simple-injector

I was reading this SO question:

[SetResolver in console application using Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084646/setresolver-in-console-application-using-simple-injector)

In it, I see this remark:

> I fixed this and pushed v2.8.2 of the CommonServiceLocator adapter to
>   NuGet. But note that we are dropping support for the CSL adapter in v3
>   of Simple Injector because it leads to bad practice. Don't use it; you
>   don't need it.

Just what does this mean?

Does this mean that this code will no longer work?

```
// configuration
var container = new Container();
InitializeContainer(container);
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

// access
var container = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;
var myObject = container.GetService(typeof(MyObject)) as MyObject;
```

If so, could I register a vote that this access ***not*** be removed? We don't use the service locator pattern often, but we have a couple of critical bits of functionality where we simply don't have any other choice. If we can't use DependencyResolver, we're forced back to using static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just what does this mean?

It means that from [v3 and beyond](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/26) we will not support a NuGet package for the [Common Service Locator](https://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) project. That's it. Nothing more; nothing less.

So this means that if you want to use the **Common Service Locator** project, you can try using the [CommonServiceLocator.SimpleInjector NuGet package for v2.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.SimpleInjectorAdapter/) that is not guaranteed to keep working in newer versions of v3 and beyond. So it might be wiser to [write your own adapter](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/26).

What this doesn't mean is that we drop support for Web API, MVC and all other frameworks that use some sort of `IDependencyResolver` adapter. There are integration packages available and they are still supported. So the code examples [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html) and [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html) are still correct and your code example should work just fine.